# How to make my Google Form fields populate individual rows in the results spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-forms

I'm setting up a form where people can submit orders. I'd like to make it so that each order populates a new row. Currently, the output looks like this:

Submitter Name; Orders

Bob;Order1, Order2, Order3, Order4

Instead, I'd like it to look like this:

Submitter Name; Orders

Bob; Order 1

Bob; Order 2

Bob; Order 3

Bob; Order 4

Is there any way to do this? I don't really know Javascript but I'm willing to do any crash-coursing necessary to figure this out.

Edit for more details: Essentially my ideal form would have a drop-down where you select how many orders you want to submit, then the form gives you a variable number of fields depending on what you selected. After submission, each order field shows up as a new row in the spreadsheet, instead of all being in the same row.

Answer (score 1):

your question is not clear. You don't need JS to make Google Form work correctly. Please share the link of your form. Every time someone fills the form, it automatically adds to the new row. Kindly share some more details.

Comment: I want it to make new multiple rows from a single submission. Bob would submit the form once with all of his orders, and the spreadsheet creates a new row for each order.

Comment: I have extensively worked with forms and I don't think there is any way of customising how to store responses; you may try other form-service-providers.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Do you happen to have any recommendations?

Comment: Google and search for Typeform, maybe you can find solution there.